# s3sync on ruby 1.9.2 not working

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

This is a long running issue which I have faced, not being able to use s3sync and s3cmd from ruby ver 1.9.2, although it works fine under ruby 1.8.7.

Tried making the changes as give [here](http://code.google.com/p/s3sync-s3cmd/issues/detail?id=7)

```
lib/HTTPStreaming.rb is missing the line:
    require 'delegate')
```

Gets me past first level of error but then i get 403 Forbidden error.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in the new gem - **frahugo-s3sync** (1.3.8)

Seems to work in the initial tests.

Comment: If this solved the problem, please mark it as accepted so that this question won't show up in the 'unanswered' list.

Answer (score 1):

Another fork that works fine with Ruby 1.9.x is https://github.com/aproxacs/s3sync.